# EXCEL formula to sum demand per date when multiple entries of dates exist

Tags: excel, sum, sumproduct

How do I sum the amount of demand I have for each date, when there are multiple entries for each date., e.g.

```
Sheet 1:
  A              B          
Date          Demand
13/7/21         5
13/7/21         4
13/7/21         2
15/7/21         6
15/7/21         3
16/7/21         2
16/7/21         4

So I'm trying to get a summary as follows:
Sheet 2:
 A              B
13/7/21         11
14/7/21          0
15/7/21          9
16/7/21          6
17/7/21          0
```

I've tried =SUMPRODUCT(--('Sheet 1'!$A$2:$A$240='Sheet 2'!A2),'Sheet 1'!$B$1:$B$240)

I'm not wanting to do a pivot table, as the pivot table does not give me the zero values for dates where there is no data (unless there is a way to show this in a pivot)

Comment: Try sumif() or sumifs().

Comment: What about the `Subtotals` basic Excel feature? You get the sum for each date and the total sum as a plus :-)

Answer (score 0):

Put together quickly to start you off:
Edit to give text version of the solution to the OP's problem:

```
=SUMIFS(B6:B12,A6:A12,"="&G12)
```

[image]

Then you can do between by setting lower and upper criteria in the sumifs().

Comment: You no need `>` or `<` to solve OP's problem. Also you must put formula as text not as screenshot. There are many other formula we can use to solve the problem like `SUMPRODUCT()`, `FILTER()` etc...

Comment: @Harun24HR then your own answer is missing every possible method of completing the task set by the Op... And the direct solution is shown for the op.

Comment: Because other methods depend on version of excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMIFS()` like

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A,A1)
```

You can also use `SUMPRODUCT()` in this way.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$B$2:$B$8)*(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$8=A1))
```

[image]

Comment: Shame you don't show the before and after options like I did...